# Comparing two parameters in a SQL Server function

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
Create Function GetProducts (@AttributeValue NVARCHAR(max)) 
RETURNS NVARCHAR  
AS  
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @CountA INT  
    DECLARE @CountB INT  
    DECLARE @ProductValue NVARCHAR(max)

    SELECT @CountA = Count(*) 
    FROM CRM_fn_ac(@AttributeValue)

    SELECT @CountB = Count(*) 
    FROM product 
    WHERE filteredviewname = 'filteredciti_ac 
      AND attributename ='c_products' 
      AND value IN (SELECT * FROM CRM_fn_ac(@AttributeValue)

   IF @CountA =@CountB
   BEGIN
       SELECT @ProductValue= @AttributeValue
   END

   RETURN @ProductValue
END
```

I'm getting an error near the `IF` condition. I want to set

```
productvalue = attributevalue when CountA = CountB
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: You are missing a bracket just before the if statement closing off your inner select

Comment: When you are giving a value to @CountB, you are saying AND VALUE IN... and then doing a SELECT *.. Is this correct? Does the function return only 1 column?

Comment: Incorrect Syntax near If Expecting (, UNION or EXCEPT

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring `NVARCHAR` without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `nvarchar` variables and parameters that you use

Comment: @user3832180 did you manage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the missing bracket...

Change this :

```
SELECT @CountB = Count() from product where filteredviewname='filteredciti_ac and attributename ='c_products' and value in (select * from CRM_fn_ac(@AttributeValue)
```

To this :

```
 SELECT @CountB = Count() from product where filteredviewname='filteredciti_ac' and attributename ='c_products' and value in (select * from CRM_fn_ac(@AttributeValue))
```

You also forgot to close the single quotes when filtering on the column **filteredviewname**...